# Communication between two Docker containers

Tags: python, docker

I'm using Docker with two containers. One of these is a simple server written in Python:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Flask Dockerized'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

The second one is simple client: i.e.

```
r = requests.get('http://localhost:5000')
```

How can I make them know each other, if both of them run in different containers?

Comment: There are a few ways. The way I typically use (I think it's outdated now) is to `EXPOSE` the ports in the server container and then link the client container to it using `--link`. This will add an entry into the client's `/etc/hosts` file that will allow you to reference the server within the client app (using something like e.g. `requests.get('flask:5000')` for a linked running container named 'flask' that exposes port 5000).

Comment: A better alternative to this would be to use Docker compose to define both the server and client images. This will allow you to start both apps together in their own isolated network, and the server will automatically be discoverable from the client app using a hostname identical to the container name. https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: name your second container with `--name <second_container>`. Run your first container with `--link <second_container>`. You will be able to request simply using `r = requests.get('<second_container>')` from first container.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a platform like [Cycle](http://cycle.io) you can use hostnames to connect containers via encrypted private networks.

Disclaimer: I'm a developer at Cycle.

P.S.  Here's a link you can use to try it out: 
https://portal.cycle.io/signup?code=JO4J8BM